# Value compared to value always returns false in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this method using AngularJS:

```
app.controller("HomeController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.btnText = "Login";
    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.btnText = "Please wait...";
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/Home/UserLogin',
            data: $scope.user
        }).then(function (d) {
            debugger;
            $scope.btnText = 'Login';
            if (d == "1") {
                window.location.href = '/Home/Dashboard';
            } else {
                alert(d.toString());
            }
            $scope.user = null;
        });
    }
});
```

I get this result:

```
d = {data: "1", status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ}
```

This means that d = 1. Why is it that I always get false on my comparison statement? I tried:
d === 1; d == '1'; d.toString() == "1"; d.toString() == '1'; still, I get false.

Comment: Isn't it d.data == "1"?

Comment: It's a mystery to me why you would claim, after pointing out that `d = {data: "1", ...}`, that *d = 1*. That's just obviously wrong. How could an object be equal to the constant `1`, or be equal to the value of one of its properties? I suggest you close this question, since it is unlikely to be interesting to any other current or future readers of Stack Overflow. By the way, please don't tag questions with tags like "angularjs" if it is not related to AngularJS, just as you would not tag the question "living room" because it happened in your living room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this **`(d.data === "1")`**,

```
if (d.data === "1") {
   window.location.href = '/Home/Dashboard';
} else {
  alert(d.data.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

d is the entire response which have a key `data` . So doing `d.data` will give value of `data`. Also note the use of triple `=` operator

In your case `==` operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. `===` operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type `===` will simply return false.

```
if (d.data === "1") { // Rest of the code}
```

Comment: same answer below

Comment: @Sajeetharan we both answered hardly few seconds apart